# Python script with arguments in PHP

Tags: php, python

I have a python script in a folder, which I run from the terminal like this:

```
python3 inference.py --model pretrained/photo2monet.pb --input input.jpg --output output.jpg --image_size 256
```

I would like to have this command run automatically on a PHP file.

I tried with:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 inference.py --model pretrained/photo2monet.pb --input input.jpg --output output.jpg --image_size 256');
shell_exec ($command);
```

But nothing happens. It should generate an image. Instead from terminal my command works. What can I do?

Comment: Are you running the PHP script in the same folder?

Comment: Of course! @Barmar

Comment: Try redirecting the error output by putting `2>&1` at the end of the command. And then print the result of `shell_exec`.

Comment: @Barmar `Unknown option: --
usage: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try python -h for more information.`

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but what happens if you don't use `escapeshellcmd`?

Comment: I also tried to run only `shell_exec('python3 --model pretrained/photo2monet.pb --input input.jpg --output output.jpg --image_size 256');`  Same result, nothing happens. It seems that the double indent is not recognized. It seems strange to me

Comment: Again, use `2>&1` to see the error.

Comment: What do you mean by double indent? Do you mean double hyphen `--`?

Comment: You're missing `inference.py` in that command.

Comment: Are you sure you have `inference.py` in the original `$command`? You'll get that error if you give the `--model` option to Python instead of giving it after the script name.

Comment: Type `python3 --model` in the terminal and you'll see the same error.

Comment: I forgot it because I wrote the comment by heart, but in the code there is. However, if I run `php upload.php` from the terminal, the command works. The problem seems to be when it runs on the php page call.

Comment: I don't think it's there. That's exactly the error you would expect if you didn't put `inference.py` as the first argument. Check again. Show me the output of `echo $command;`

Comment: Look here this: https://imgur.com/7j4zWjD

Comment: If I run `php upload.php` from terminal it works, it generates the output. If instead the command is executed from the php web page on call no

Comment: The web page is running in a different directory. Put full pathnames for the script, input, and output files.

Comment: But the php script, the python file and the input are all in the same directory

Comment: Try the full path to the `python3` executable, maybe it's not in the webserver's `$PATH`.

Comment: If it were not in the `$PATH` I should not be able to run even from the terminal, instead from the terminal it works very well

Comment: Your `$PATH` is different from the webserver's, it's customized in one of your shell startup files.

Comment: Put `echo shell_exec('type python3');` in the script, and compare the difference when you run it from terminal and webserver.

Comment: Interesting. From terminal is `/usr/local/bin/python3`. From URL `http://192.168.64.2/api_demo/upload.php` is **python3 not found**

Comment: I told you. The webserver doesn't have `/usr/local/bin` in its search path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the full pathname to the `python3` executable, it's not in the webserver's `$PATH`.

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/local/bin/python3 inference.py --model pretrained/photo2monet.pb --input input.jpg --output output.jpg --image_size 256');
```

Comment: However even inserting the full python3 path does not work :(

Comment: I can't understand it. I specified the absolute PATH of the python3 executable in the command but it still doesn't work. I don't know what else to check

Comment: `$debug = exec('/usr/local/bin/python3 inference.py --model pretrained/photo2monet.pb --input input.jpg --output output.jpg --image_size 256');` and  `echo $debug;` and the page remains blank, it seems that there is no error

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the end of the command so you get the error messages. I told you that an hour ago.

Comment: `sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/python3: not found` wtf?

Comment: `which python3`, result `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: Maybe the webserver is running PHP in a chroot environment? What does `echo shell_exec('ls /usr/local/bin 2>&1')` show?

Comment: The page remains white, there is no output with `echo shell_exec('ls /usr/local/bin 2>&1')`

Comment: I solved by installing MAMP and working directly in /home